# How to come back to Caller Service Class Back from a Async method

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a service called `UseCaseService`, which calls an asynchronous method of another service called `PublishUseCaseService`. Since the publishing process is a long-running task, I want my current API to return a 200 OK status. Once the async method is finished, successfully or not, I need to update the status in my `UseCase`.

Since `PublishUseCaseService` is already added as a dependency in `UseCaseService`, I can't add `UseCaseService` in `PublishUseCaseService` as it would create a cyclic dependency.

I am wondering how I can achieve this. I have tried setting up a Job Service and creating a job, but it still has some issues and isn't working as I expected. I am wondering if there is an easier way to achieve this or some other concept that I am unaware of, as the asynchronous topic is totally new to me.

Comment: Now if only you could fire an event and have listener for a completed event. Or return a `CompletableFuture` from the `PublishUseCaseService` service method and do a callback upon completion. THen you are still inside the `UseCaseService`.

Comment: If possible make your method in UseCaseService as async. And then call the desired method of PublishUseCaseService from UseCaseService after the process gets completed.